# Construct a calculus which produces exactly all pairs $(S,t)$, such that $free(t)=S$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Construct a calculus which produces exactly all pairs $(S,t)$, such that $free(t)=S$. This calculus will operate on pairs $(S,t)$, where $S$ is a set of variables and t is a term.

I've got an understanding of free vs bound variable.

for instance, $x^y$, $x$ is bound and $y$ is free.

If I understand the rule or rules I construct for this calculus will be such that any term $t$ will contain all free variables that are in contained in $S$ and any term in $S$ will satisfy this.

I'm not sure what rules I need exactly, maybe

a rule to construct  variables, and a rule that generates terms with some n-ary function. But anything quantified is bounded so then that variable is no longer free.

Comment: Terms have only free variables. So you can use the usual term calculus and just take as S all variables in t.

Comment: @Sebastian so if I have some function f that is n-ary and a rule that generates a term that contains the terms before it all. The amount of free variables will not change and each term will contain the same amount of free variable thus $free(t_i) = S, i \in \{1,...,n\}$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Note that in a term all variables are free. So the following calculus will do:

$${\over (\{v_n\}, v_n)} $$ where $v_n$ is a variable.
$${\over (\emptyset, c)}$$ where c is a constant symbols.
$${(S_1, t_1) \\ \dots \\ (S_n, t_n) \over ( \bigcup_i S_i, ft_1\dots t_n) }$$

where f is an n-ary function symbol.